# Linphone is not sending re-INVITE message

Tags: sip, kamailio

I'm trying to implement a SIP mid-call mobility using Linphone as UA and Kamailio as SIP proxy/registrar. I start the communication between two UAs in the same network (A) then I move one of the UAs to a network (B). According to RFC 3261, linphone (or any other UA compliant to it) should send a re-INVITE message to the other UA (another user using linphone) in order to inform him about his new IP in the network (B), but This is not happening and linphone is not sending the re-INVITE  ..... and the conversation stops.
    Can you please help to solve this problem ?
    I want to know if the re-INVITE features is supported by default in linphone ? if not how could I activate it ? or if you see flaws/problems in the architecture I described, please tell how to fix it.
    Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Nop ....the linephone doesn't support the mobility. So it will never send an re-INVITE MESSAGE

Comment: stuck on same problem.. Please provide solution if you find one.

Comment: I never found a solution, but I don't know the newer versions of Linphone fixed the issue or not

Comment: does anyone where this stands ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old post, but as an update: Linphone does nowadays (2020) support mid-call mobility. It sends a reINVITE with 'Subject: Media Change' on every network change.

Comment: yes indeed its a very old post, but thanks for the answer